# Query MySQL on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone i have some question about query on mysql.
I have some code like this

```sql
SELECT site.id, site.name_site, site.id_site,site.id_mast,site.address,site.types,
       site.longtitude,site.latitude,site.altitude, site.id_region as site, 
       region.name_region, region.id_region as region 
       FROM site as site 
       INNER JOIN region as region 
       ON site.id_region = region.id_region ORDER BY name_site limit 3;
```

And also this work:

```sql
SELECT * FROM site, region WHERE site.id_region= region.id_region LIMIT 2;
```

On browser nothing happen, byt on mysql this work, but not on PHP. Why i have some mistake on script  php or have problem with query mysql?
Please help me.
Thanks for all hints.

```
<?php

$dbhost = '............';
$dbuser = '........';
$dbpass = '.......';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM site, region WHERE site.id_region= region.id_region LIMIT 2;");
mysql_select_db('db_site', $conn) or die ('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
?>
<h4><center>Title</center></h4>
<table border='2' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr>
<td>id</td>
<td>id_site</td>
<td>id_mast</td>
<td>name_site</td>
<td>address</td>
<td>types</td>
<td>longtitude</td>
<td>latitude</td>
<td>altitude</td>
<td>id_region</td>
</tr>
<?php

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn ) or die ('Error did not connection'. mysql_error());
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
print "<tr>";
print "<td>{$row['id']}</td>";
print "<td>{$row['id_site']}</td>";
print "<td>{$row['id_mast']}</td>";
print "<td>{$row['name_site']}</td>";
print "<td style='width:100;'>{$row['address']}</td>";
print "<td style='width:100;'>{$row['types']}</td>";
print "<td>{$row['longtitude']}</td>";
print "<td>{$row['latitude']}</td>";
print "<td>{$row['altitude']}</td>";
print "<td>{$row['id_region']}</td>";
print "</tr>";
}
print "</table>";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Thanks for all hints. Thanks

Comment: How do you run in on PHP and what do you expect to happen ?

Comment: .. and what does happen? Do you get an error?

Comment: I hope you haven't literally pasted the MySQL code onto a `.php` file

Comment: you should learn what alias does. and... where is the php code?

Comment: I expect connect two different tables. One of them have id_region some connect to table region.

Comment: Edit the question with the PHP code

Comment: edit your question to add your php code

Comment: even Jon Skeet can't help you with this one xD

Comment: There is so much wrong with your code...

Comment: I just edit to html and php code `<td>name_region</td>` and `print "<td>{$row['name-region']}</td>";` I got another problems.  Name region not come to colum name_region whay?

Comment: maybe you should use "name_region" instead of name-region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove the simple quotes in your printf: `$row['id_region']` becames `$row[id_region]` but I suggest you this to be sure:

```
echo '<td>'.$row['id_region'].'</td>';
```

Also, please consider using mysqli instead of mysql, as it's deprecated

```
<?php

$dbhost = '............';
$dbuser = '........';
$dbpass = '.......';
$dbname = 'db_site';
$my = new Mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

?>
<h4><center>Title</center></h4>
<table border='2' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
<tr>
<td>id</td>
<td>id_site</td>
<td>id_mast</td>
<td>name_site</td>
<td>address</td>
<td>types</td>
<td>longtitude</td>
<td>latitude</td>
<td>altitude</td>
<td>id_region</td>
</tr>
<?php

// create a db connexion
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM site, region WHERE site.id_region= region.id_region LIMIT 2;';
// make the query
$stmt = $my->query($sql);
// fetch the results, display them as you want
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc())
{
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['id_site'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['id_mast'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['name_site'].'</td>';
  echo '<td style="width:100;">'.$row['address'].'</td>';
  echo '<td style="width:100;">'.$row['types'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['longtitude'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['latitude'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['altitude'].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$row['id_region'].'</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```